# Repeat AnimationDrawable every few seconds

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-animation

I have an AnimationDrawable that animates a set of frame images.
How do I implement a restart every 10 seconds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, just give your last frame 10 second extra. Example -

```
    <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:oneshot="false">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/image" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/image3" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/image4" android:duration="10100" />
 </animation-list>
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this from code, in a more "elegant" way, like using some sort of timer or handler (which I'm not sure how to do)?

Comment: You can do it using timer also, but I think this is the best way to do it, because the all delay and restarting animation will be done by same thread. If you want to handle it using timer, then timer will unnecessarily create one more extra thread. So I will never recommend using timer or handler .

Comment: OK. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = -1;

Timer mTimer = new Timer();
mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            count++;
            if (count >= imageArray.length)
                count = 0;

            MyImageView.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);
        }
    });
}
}, 0, 10000);
```